# Sorting rows of data frame based on time stamp

Tags: r, sorting

I have a data frame, the rows of which I would like to sort based on time stamp.

```
                     V1    V2                     V3    V4                     V5    V6
1 {"2014-08-01T01:00:00": "64", "2014-08-01T13:00:00": "53", "2014-08-01T01:20:00": "73",
2 {"2014-08-02T18:00:00": "37", "2014-08-02T22:00:00": "56", "2014-08-02T17:00:00": "24",
3 {"2014-08-03T17:50:00": "78", "2014-08-03T04:20:00": "83", "2014-08-03T00:20:00": "73",
4 {"2014-08-04T15:00:00": "37", "2014-08-04T21:00:00": "39", "2014-08-04T15:20:00": "43",
5 {"2014-08-05T19:20:00": "78", "2014-08-05T13:20:00": "46", "2014-08-05T00:00:00": "62",
6 {"2014-08-06T11:00:00": "45", "2014-08-06T09:00:00": "56", "2014-08-06T21:50:00": "68",
                      V7    V8                     V9   V10                    V11   V12
1 "2014-08-01T13:20:00": "57", "2014-08-01T13:50:00": "47", "2014-08-01T20:50:00": "44",
2 "2014-08-02T01:00:00": "56", "2014-08-02T17:20:00": "42", "2014-08-02T01:20:00": "68",
3 "2014-08-03T23:00:00": "81", "2014-08-03T00:00:00": "63", "2014-08-03T00:50:00": "73",
4 "2014-08-04T02:00:00": "81", "2014-08-04T18:00:00": "29", "2014-08-04T02:20:00": "88",
5 "2014-08-05T00:20:00": "72", "2014-08-05T00:50:00": "77", "2014-08-05T19:00:00": "75",
6 "2014-08-06T14:20:00": "53", "2014-08-06T14:00:00": "40", "2014-08-06T23:20:00": "77",
```

**Desired out**

The output of only one row is shown below.

```
{"2014-08-01T01:00:00": "64",   "2014-08-01T01:20:00":  "73",   "2014-08-01T13:00:00":  "53",   "2014-08-01T13:20:00":  "57",   "2014-08-01T13:50:00":  "47",   "2014-08-01T20:50:00":  "44",
```

Comment: In what language are your data?

Comment: Input and output are not a valid format in R. What is the source of the data?

Comment: Is this data structure supposed to be json? Something else? Order of keys is undefined in json objects. Use an array.

Comment: The code you provide is not a valid data frame.  It is not even valid R. The order of keys in json objects is not defined so even if you manage to output the line you want, when your object is read by a function into an R list for example, the order is not going to be respected. I would recommend to rethink your problem and desired solution and if you still need help write down a REPRODUCIBLE piece of code that illustrates the problem and desired solution output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We convert the datetime columns (`df2[c(TRUE, FALSE)]`- we are subsetting by recycling the logical vector) to `POSIXct` class by looping through the columns with `lapply`, then `order` by row using `apply` with `MARGIN=1` ('m1').  We `split` the time columns and the value columns by row to create two lists 'l1', 'l2', then use `Map` with `paste` to concatenate the string together after we order the elements based on 'm1'.  This can be converted to `data.frame` with one column.

```
 df2[c(TRUE, FALSE)] <- lapply(df1[c(TRUE, FALSE)], function(x) as.POSIXct(sub('[{]', '', x), format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:'))
 m1 <- apply(df2[c(TRUE, FALSE)], 1, order)
 l1 <- split(as.matrix(df1[c(TRUE, FALSE)]), row(df1[c(TRUE, FALSE)]))
 l2 <- split(as.matrix(df2[c(FALSE, TRUE)]), row(df2[c( FALSE, TRUE)]))


data.frame(col1=unlist(Map(function(x,y,z) paste0('{', 
               paste(gsub('^\\{*(\\d+.*)(\\:)', '"\\1"\\2', x[z]),
                     gsub('(\\d+)', '"\\1"', y[z]), sep=' ', collapse=' ')),
                 l1, l2, split(m1, col(m1)))), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
                                                                                                                                                                            col1
#1 {"2014-08-01T01:00:00": "64", "2014-08-01T01:20:00": "73", "2014-08-01T13:00:00": "53", "2014-08-01T13:20:00": "57", "2014-08-01T13:50:00": "47", "2014-08-01T20:50:00": "44",
#2 {"2014-08-02T01:00:00": "56", "2014-08-02T01:20:00": "68", "2014-08-02T17:00:00": "24", "2014-08-02T17:20:00": "42", "2014-08-02T18:00:00": "37", "2014-08-02T22:00:00": "56",
#3 {"2014-08-03T00:00:00": "63", "2014-08-03T00:20:00": "73", "2014-08-03T00:50:00": "73", "2014-08-03T04:20:00": "83", "2014-08-03T17:50:00": "78", "2014-08-03T23:00:00": "81",
#4 {"2014-08-04T02:00:00": "81", "2014-08-04T02:20:00": "88", "2014-08-04T15:00:00": "37", "2014-08-04T15:20:00": "43", "2014-08-04T18:00:00": "29", "2014-08-04T21:00:00": "39",
#5 {"2014-08-05T00:00:00": "62", "2014-08-05T00:20:00": "72", "2014-08-05T00:50:00": "77", "2014-08-05T13:20:00": "46", "2014-08-05T19:00:00": "75", "2014-08-05T19:20:00": "78",
#6 {"2014-08-06T09:00:00": "56", "2014-08-06T11:00:00": "45", "2014-08-06T14:00:00": "40", "2014-08-06T14:20:00": "53", "2014-08-06T21:50:00": "68", "2014-08-06T23:20:00": "77",
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines(textConnection('V1    V2                     V3    V4                     V5    V6
1 {"2014-08-01T01:00:00": "64", "2014-08-01T13:00:00": "53", "2014-08-01T01:20:00": "73",
2 {"2014-08-02T18:00:00": "37", "2014-08-02T22:00:00": "56", "2014-08-02T17:00:00": "24",
3 {"2014-08-03T17:50:00": "78", "2014-08-03T04:20:00": "83", "2014-08-03T00:20:00": "73",
4 {"2014-08-04T15:00:00": "37", "2014-08-04T21:00:00": "39", "2014-08-04T15:20:00": "43",
5 {"2014-08-05T19:20:00": "78", "2014-08-05T13:20:00": "46", "2014-08-05T00:00:00": "62",
6 {"2014-08-06T11:00:00": "45", "2014-08-06T09:00:00": "56", "2014-08-06T21:50:00": "68",'))

lines2 <- readLines(textConnection('V7    V8                     V9   V10                    V11   V12
1 "2014-08-01T13:20:00": "57", "2014-08-01T13:50:00": "47", "2014-08-01T20:50:00": "44",
2 "2014-08-02T01:00:00": "56", "2014-08-02T17:20:00": "42", "2014-08-02T01:20:00": "68",
3 "2014-08-03T23:00:00": "81", "2014-08-03T00:00:00": "63", "2014-08-03T00:50:00": "73",
4 "2014-08-04T02:00:00": "81", "2014-08-04T18:00:00": "29", "2014-08-04T02:20:00": "88",
5 "2014-08-05T00:20:00": "72", "2014-08-05T00:50:00": "77", "2014-08-05T19:00:00": "75",
6 "2014-08-06T14:20:00": "53", "2014-08-06T14:00:00": "40", "2014-08-06T23:20:00": "77",'))

 d1 <- read.table(text=gsub('^\\d+\\s+|"', '', lines), header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 d2 <- read.table(text=gsub('^\\d+\\s+|"', '', lines2), header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 df1 <- cbind(d1, d2)
 df2 <- df1
```